# Reduce docker image size of tensorflow

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am trying to create docker image of tensorflow with less than **1GB** of size. I am using tensorflow 2.12 version.

Below is my requirement.txt file,

```
#Requirement.txt
fastapi==0.108.0
pip==22.0.4
tensorflow==2.12
```

and here is my dockerfile,

```
FROM python:3.8.10-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 


ARG TF_PACKAGE=tensorflow
ARG TF_PACKAGE_VERSION=2.12
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir ${TF_PACKAGE}${TF_PACKAGE_VERSION:+==${TF_PACKAGE_VERSION}}
```

Currently the image size is **1.94GB** , is there any way to reduce this below 1GB?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you take a look at official docker images provided by [tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/).